# Redirect latex.stackexchange.com subdomain

Tags: feature-request

Shouldn't latex.stackexchange.com  redirect to tex.stackexchange.com?

Even the title of the page says 'TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange'

Answer (score 6):

I personally don't think that is necessary. OK, some people only know LaTeX but have no idea what TeX is, but as the OP already says: LaTeX is in the title and the description. Also you will find the site with Google easily when you search for LaTeX.

Having two names will just create some confusion IMHO. Also AFAIK the Stack Exchange admins stopped allowing alternative names for SX sites a while ago. Before that we could have had a 'something.com' alias as well.

Comment: I think you're right in that there's no need for a redirect, but the SE rule isn't not necessarily a fast one.  maths.stackoverflow.com is a redirect for math.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That's fine for a one-off spelling issue, but with TeX.SX we have a number of potential 'other names'.

Comment: @JosephWright: Absolutely!  I *completely agree* that there shouldn't be a redirect in this case.  My inner mathematician, though, wouldn't let me let Martin's second paragraph stand uncontested.

Comment: Yes, `htlualatex.stackexchange.com` should redirect here if that's what you're used to typing ;-)

Comment: I want to agree, but I have to play devil's advocate here: latex is likely much more well-known than tex (especially among those people who just use it and don't know much about the internals: aka those who need our help the most).  Obviously there are several 'other names' (including potentially can-of-worms ones like context) but it bothers me that latex in particular is not an alias.